# The difference between "auch wenn" and "selbst wenn"

Tags: difference, adverb

What is the difference between *auch wenn* and *selbst wenn*:

> 1. ***Auch wenn*** ich dir die Wahrheit erzählt hätte, würdest du mir übrigens nicht glauben.
> 2. ***Selbst wenn*** ich dir die Wahrheit erzählt hätte, würdest du mir übrigens nicht glauben.

Even if I told you the truth, you wouldn't believe me anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference actually is

- **selbst wenn** and **auch wenn** are used for hypothetical cases (*even if*) (see: irrealer Einräumungssatz <sup>[(1)](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Konzessivsatz.html)</sup>)
- but only **auch wenn** is used for real ones (*even though*)

Examples:

> Selbst wenn ich das versuchen würde / Even if I tried
>
> Auch wenn das ein Problem ist / Even though it's a problem

Comment: also read here: http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=401760&idForum=4&lang=de&lp=ende

Answer (score 7):

The meaning of both in this usage is similar.

*Selbst wenn* has a slight connotation of being stronger, and is sometimes used without the remaining sentence colloquially:

> "Und was ist, wenn X passiert?" - "Selbst wenn... (dann ändert das auch nichts.)"

This usage is not possible with "Auch wenn".

I'd use "selbst wenn" if I wouldn't ever intend to do the thing (here: telling the truth) because it just doesn't make sense to do it, while "auch wenn" seems more like I could do that if required, but won't do (or did not do it yet). You'd be understood with both versions anyway.

RayofCommand's answer, which states that both are exactly the same, actually adds an interesting twist to it by using 
"Auch wenn" in a slightly different meaning, because

> "Auch wenn er nur eine Maschine ist"

is more like

> "Even *though* it's just a machine"

and can also be substituted with

> "Obwohl er nur eine Maschine ist."

In that case, "selbst wenn" doesn't work as intended.
Note that these examples are different from the usage you asked about.

Comment: really nice observations. They are almost different but not entirely

Comment: Insgesamt +1, aber Konotation ist mal wieder falsch eingesetzt, und selbst wenn ich darüber hinwegesehe gehe ich da nicht mit. Das eine ist nicht stärker als das andere.

Answer (score 5):

With reference to OPs example (namely referring to an action in the past which does not happen and thus we cannot tell what have happened if we did the action), *selbst wenn* is a little more flexible than *auch wenn*.

*Selbst wenn* has two connotations:

- [a] **It doesn't matter** if something happened or was true. I wouldn't have cared **anyway**.
- [b] **Assuming** something happened or was true, **even then** I wouldn't have cared.

*Auch wenn* conveys only the latter connotation [b].

Examples:

> Er hatte kein Geld. Aber er hätte die Jacke gekauft, auch (dann) wenn ich ihm gesagt hätte, dass sie zu klein ist (=Sogar dann, wenn ich es ihm gesagt hätte -> [b]).
>
> Er hatte kein Geld. Aber er hätte die Jacke gekauft, selbst wenn ich ihm gesagt hätte, dass sie zu klein ist (=Unbeachtet dessen, was ich gesagt hätte -> [a]).
>
> Er hatte kein Geld. Aber er hätte die Jacke gekauft, selbst (dann) wenn ich ihm gesagt hätte, dass sie zu klein ist (=Sogar dann, wenn ich es ihm gesagt hätte -> [b]).

It's different if we're talking about an action what not happened yet (which is mainly addressed by the answer of @falkb). In that case *auch wenn* is more flexible than *selbst wenn*.

Now *auch wenn* has two connotations:

- [a] **It doesn't matter** if something will happen or is true. I will not care **anyway**.
- [b] **Although** something happened or is true, I will not care.

*Selbst wenn* only connotes the former one here [a].

Examples:

> Ich werde die Jacke kaufen, selbst wenn sie zu klein ist (=Ich weiß nicht, ob sie zu klein ist -> [a]).
>
> Ich werde die Jacke kaufen, auch wenn sie zu klein ist (=Ich weiß sie ist zu klein -> [b]).
>
> Ich werde die Jacke kaufen, auch (dann) wenn sie zu klein ist (=Ich weiß nicht, ob sie zu klein ist -> [a]).

Comment: Apart for the grammarians: *auch wenn* and *selbst wenn* are `Fokuspartikel`.

Comment: Wenn das alles Nebenbedeutungen sind, was ist dann die Hauptbedeutung?

Answer (score -1):

They’re synonymous and there’s no difference between them. Check grammatical sources for this. This thread is needlessly complicated.

> [a] It doesn’t matter if something happened or was true. I wouldn’t have cared anyway.
>   [b] Assuming something happened or was true, even then I wouldn’t have cared."

You do realize [a] entails [b] right? Not caring about something means by definition having a completely neutral reaction or indifference to it. It entails you would have the same reaction whether or not that thing happens or exists.

Das gilt ebenso für das mit der Jacke. Dass er die Jacke gekauft hätte, ohne zu beachten was du ihm gesagt hättest, heißt folgerecht dass ihm egal gewesen wäre, was du zu sagen gehabt hättest.

Comment: This is a Q&A site for those interested in the *finer* points of language. There is a difference between them as exchanging one for the other can modify the meaning of a sentence.