# Unterschied zwischen »auch wenn«, »wenn auch«, »selbst wenn« und »wenn selbst«

Tags: difference

Ich möchte den Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Phrasen wissen:

> - auch wenn
> - wenn auch
> - selbst wenn
> - wenn selbst

Ist »auch wenn« analog zu »obwohl«?
Ist »wenn auch« einfach ein »wenn«-Satz?
Wann kann ich »wenn auch« gegen »auch wenn« tauschen?
Wann kann ich das mit »obwohl« oder »wenn« ersetzen?

Comment: Related: [The difference between “auch wenn” and “selbst wenn”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8668/9551)

Comment: Danke, das ist ähnlich, aber nicht ganz. Meine Frage ist allgemeiner.

Comment: Wörterbuchrecherche?

Comment: @Deni: Or at least not, until you give me a clarification on 'allgemeiner'

Comment: All I can say is that in German it is a little bit of a mess with these words - a bit like the modern usage of the 'Konjunktiv'

Comment: Mit 'es wurde...' meinst Du 'von Dir' in deiner Frage oder im link?

Comment: @Deni: Ich wollte soeben deine Frage korrigieren, bin aber daran gescheitert, dass ich nicht mal ansatzweise verstehe, was du mit deinem letzten Satz (der Frage) meinst. Dieser Satz ist so verdreht, dass es mir nicht gelingt zu erraten, was gemeint sein könnte. Kannst du bitte dieses Satz so umformulieren, dass daraus ein grammatisch korrekter Satz wird? - Danke!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Analogie zwischen 'Obwohl' / 'selbst wenn' vs. 'auch wenn' / selbst wenn'...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: - Ist "auch wenn" ein **'Obwohl-Analog'** und "wenn auch" einfach ein '**Wenn-Satz**'?

Answer (score 3):

Bevor du dich fragst ob es eine Bedingung ausdrücken sollte oder nicht solltest Du auch noch die Absicht einer 'Übereinstimmung' oder eines 'Widerspruchs' in Betracht ziehen. Hier unterscheidet sich der Gebrauch der verschiedenen Wörter nämlich.

1. **Obwohl**: z.B., *etwas ist so*.

> [ich räume ein] -> und obwohl *es so ist*, werde ich...

2. **Wenn** (konditional nicht temporal): Bedingt immer etwas

> *etwas ist so* -> aber wenn es *nicht* so ist/wäre, werde/würde ich...

3. **Auch wenn** oder **selbst wenn**: wird im täglichen Sprachgebrauch für beide Fälle verwendet:

> *etwas ist so*  -> doch auch/selbst wenn *es so ist*, werde ich...  (einräumend)
>   *etwas ist so* -> doch auch/selbst wenn es *nicht* so ist/wäre, werde/würde ich... (konditional)

---

Der Alltagsgebrauch dieser deutschen Konjunktionen bietet leider keinen so guten Nährboden für eine schlüssige Erklärung oder Definition wie z.B. das Spanische, das durch einen Moduswechsel Subjuntivo/Indicativo ein und dieselbe Konjunktion sowohl z.B. konditional oder einräumend sein läßt!

aunque + Indicativo -> obwohl
aunque + Subjuntivo -> selbst wenn (konditional)

mientras + Indicativo -> während (temporal), wohingegen (adversativ)
mientras + Subjuntivo -> solange

dado que + Indicativo -> da es ja so ist, da gegeben...
dado que + Subjuntivo -> gegebenenfalls, falls es so ist (konditional)

Vielleicht habt ihr ja so etwas in Russisch auch?

---

**Wenn auch**: würde ich mal auf die Schnelle nicht als Konjunktion empfinden

> Es gibt einen Unterschied, wenn auch einen kleinen... (kein Nebensatz)

**Wenn selbst**:  als Ersatz für 'wenn sogar'

> Wenn sogar mein humorloser Lehrer darüber lacht, muss es lustig sein.

---